# How do I manually Close RadContextMenu on any of the RadMenuItem Click?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, telerik

On binding IsOpen Property with ViewModel's BOOL property isn't working.

Comment: did you try set StaysOpenOnClick to false ?

Comment: yes, but its working now, on two way binding the property.